# Fading in and out individual AVMutableCompositionTracks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avfoundation

I have multiple `AVAssets`, and I create individual `AVMutableCompositionTracks` for each. I then create an `AVMutableComposition` and add each `AVMutableCompositionTrack` to it and then create an `AVAssetExportSession`, init with the `AVMutableComposition` and run the exporter. This allows me to create a single audio file made up of many overlapping audio sources.

I can trim and delay each source audio file by setting the parameters when I `insertTimeRange` on each `AVMutableCompositionTrack`. What I can't figure out is how to fade in and out of each individual track. I can do a master fade on the export session by using setVolumeRampFromStartVolume via `AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters`, and I know how to do fades on `AVPlayer`s using the same method, but I don't think AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters can be used on an `AVMutableCompositionTrack`, right?

So how can I add a fade to a `AVMutableCompositionTrack`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters` actually can be used with `AVMutableCompositionTrack`s.  I use them.  It just isn't stored within the composition.  Instead, you'll need to set the `audioMix` property of any `AVPlayer` or `AVAssetExportSession` you use.